# Arduino vscode extension: "error: 'USB_VID' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to use the [vscode-extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino) for arduino. Always when I try to verify my code I get the following **error message**:

```
Starting] Uploading sketch 'test.ino'
Please see the build logs in output path: /home/Documents/ETH/Semester 3/Innovations Project/Software/build
In file included from /home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBAPI.h:44:0,
                 from /home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp:20:
/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp:75:29: error: 'USB_VID' was not declared in this scope
  D_DEVICE(0xEF,0x02,0x01,64,USB_VID,USB_PID,0x100,IMANUFACTURER,IPRODUCT,ISERIAL,1);
                             ^
/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.h:270:61: note: in definition of macro 'D_DEVICE'
  { 18, 1, USB_VERSION, _class,_subClass,_proto,_packetSize0,_vid,_pid,_version,_im,_ip,_is,_configs }
                                                             ^~~~
/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp:75:29: note: suggested alternative: 'USB_Recv'
  D_DEVICE(0xEF,0x02,0x01,64,USB_VID,USB_PID,0x100,IMANUFACTURER,IPRODUCT,ISERIAL,1);
                             ^
/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.h:270:61: note: in definition of macro 'D_DEVICE'
  { 18, 1, USB_VERSION, _class,_subClass,_proto,_packetSize0,_vid,_pid,_version,_im,_ip,_is,_configs }
                                                             ^~~~
/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp:75:37: error: 'USB_PID' was not declared in this scope
  D_DEVICE(0xEF,0x02,0x01,64,USB_VID,USB_PID,0x100,IMANUFACTURER,IPRODUCT,ISERIAL,1);
                                     ^
/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.h:270:66: note: in definition of macro 'D_DEVICE'
  { 18, 1, USB_VERSION, _class,_subClass,_proto,_packetSize0,_vid,_pid,_version,_im,_ip,_is,_configs }
                                                                  ^~~~
/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp:75:37: note: suggested alternative: 'USB_Recv'
  D_DEVICE(0xEF,0x02,0x01,64,USB_VID,USB_PID,0x100,IMANUFACTURER,IPRODUCT,ISERIAL,1);
                                     ^
/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/USBCore.h:270:66: note: in definition of macro 'D_DEVICE'
  { 18, 1, USB_VERSION, _class,_subClass,_proto,_packetSize0,_vid,_pid,_version,_im,_ip,_is,_configs }
                                                                  ^~~~

Error during build: exit status 1
IntelliSense configuration already up to date. To manually rebuild your IntelliSense configuration run "Ctrl+Alt+I"
[Error] Uploading sketch 'test.ino': Exit with code=1
```

The serial monitor still works in vscode and i am able to upload and verify the code using the Arduino IDE.
I can solve the error by just defining the macro in the file, but this doesn't solve the underlying issue why this occurs in the first place.

Any help is appreciated.
Best regards

The program i am testing with is a simple blink program. **test.ino**:

```
#if __has_include(<Arduino.h>)
  #include <Arduino.h>
const int ledPin = 15;

void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(100);                      // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  Serial.println(ledPin);
  delay(100);                      // wait for a second
}

#endif
```

**arduino.json**:

```
    {
    "board": "arduino:avr:micro",
    "programmer": "avrisp",
    "port": "/dev/ttyACM0",
    "output": "../build",
    "sketch": "test.ino",
    "intelliSenseGen": "global",
    "buildPreferences": [
        [
            "build.extra_flags",
            "-DMY_DEFINE=666 -DANOTHER_DEFINE=3.14 -Wall -std=c++14"
        ],
        [
            "compiler.cpp.extra_flags",
            "-DYET_ANOTER=\"hello\""
        ]
    ]
```

**task.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: avr-g++ build active file",
            "command": "/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-w",
                "-std=c++14",
                "-fpermissive",
                "-fno-exceptions",
                "-ffunction-sections",
                "-fdata-sections",
                "-fno-threadsafe-statics",
                "-Wno-error=narrowing"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

**settings.json**

```
{
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/home/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++",
    "arduino.useArduinoCli": true,
    "arduino.enableUSBDetection": true
}
```

Comment: Try verbose build. Command lines should contain something like this: `-DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8037 "-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Micro\"" -DUSB_MANUFACTURER=\"Arduino\"`. Well, you can add it as `build_flags` in platformio.ini

Comment: Thanks @KIIV ,  `-DUSB_VID=0x2341 -DUSB_PID=0x8037` fixed the error but on a separate note `-DUSB_PRODUCT=\"Arduino Micro\"` throws an error message: `avr-g++: error: Micro": No such file or directory` I think there might me a syntax error even though it looks correct to me